# Set up TeamViewer Wake On Lan - without having access to router settings

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding

I want to set up remote wake up for TeamViewer on my Windows 10 PC. The problem is that I don't have access to the router it is connected to, and I do not know which ports are forwarded (if any...). I found some online tool that checks if one single port is forwarded, but checking every possible port to find one open does not seem to be a suitable solution.

How do I:

1. Get all forwarded ports on the router, and
2. Set up some kind of WOL-ish feature?

Comment: Try re-wording your question to focus on solving the root problem, specifically *How can I set up remote wake up for TeamViewer without the ability to modify the settings of the connected router?* As written, your question is  [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) at SuperUser because you're asking for a tool (to check for forwarded ports).

Comment: In light of my edit I don't really see how this is off-topic now... The sole purpose of my edit was to make this *not* a software recommendation question.

Answer (score 4):

There is but one way: Try. You need to listen on all ports and someone on the Internet needs to try and connect to all ports.

Then you need to do it again using UDP, which is even more complicated.

However, it’s safe to assume that no ports have been forwarded. Why would they?

Whatever `netstat` says has no relation to port forwardings whatsoever.